# how to resolve/normalize URLs in GWT/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, gwt

Given two URLs, how can I resolve one of them against the other?  I'm trying to emulate Java's [URI.resolve()](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/URI.html#resolve(java.lang.String)), which does not exist in GWT's emulation library.  I've had to implement this manually, which, as you might expect has been very error-prone.  Is there a GWT or Javascript library for **resolving** or **normalizing** URLs?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it simple, create a GWT RPC to resolve urls. You can do that in 5 minutes :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used Closure's [Uri class](http://closure-library.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/closure/goog/docs/class_goog_Uri.html) to do this, which has a `resolve()` method. If you linked that in you could use GWT's [JavaScript Native Interface](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2008/07/getting-to-really-know-gwt-part-1-jsni.html) (JSNI) to write a native JavaScript method -- probably something like:

```
native String resolve(String base, String relative) /*-{
  var baseUri = goog.Uri.parse(base);
  var relativeUri = goog.Uri.parse(relative);
  return baseUri.resolve(relativeUri).toString();
}-*/;
```